# Where are these infrastructure entries coming from in AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm learning SAM, and when I create a project on my computer, following `sam init`, I can deploy it and it shows up in AWS. When I create pretty much the same project in AWS, it creates some extra entries in "Infrastructure" section of the Lambda application. These do not appear when I do `sam init` and `sam deploy`:

[image]

The entries at the bottom of that screen, in the Infrastructure section,  look essentially like what connect this SAM project to a github repo, runs the tests, deploys, etc.

Where is that infrastructure coming from? If I wanted it in another project, do I have to created it by hand or is there code I could deploy to cause that to be created in AWS?

For example, one of the things listed in "Infrastructure" is the PermissionBoundaryPolicy. For another project I created one, I added it two the SAM template, and deployed, but it won't appear there.

Comment: Suggest you edit your question to be more precise. I know SAM ok but don't understand your question.

Comment: @Tim I made some small changes to try to clarify but I'm not sure how to clarify further. There are things created by AWS when creating a lamba app that are not created by sam deploy. How do I re-create them? can it be automated? If you have a question about what's not understandable I'm happy to clarify further.

Comment: If you want help be precise. I understand "when I create a SAM project on my local computer with AWS SAM", but when you say "When I create pretty much the same project in AWS" do you mean you did it with the console or some other way? Exactly which "extra things" are created? When you say something "at the bottom of the screen" please say exactly what you mean. Also, what problem are you having? Have you read the documentation regarding how to have things appear in the "infrastructure" section? You might be better off using Super User if this is not a business problem.